# Outlook vba .sendOnBehalfOf property?

Tags: vba, outlook

I have an additional `From` account and I am using `.sendOnBehalfOf` property to send emails using `vba` .

Is there any way I could access the inbox of that mail box ? I can use it to send email, but how can I access the mailbox itself ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, use Application.Session.GetSharedDefaultFolder(recipient, olFolderInbox)